# Magento Google Checkout Change New Order Status

Tags: magento

Is there a way to change the default New Order Status in Magento's admin for Google Checkout.

In the dropdown box there is only the option to select Pending. Ideally I want to be able to set that to Processing instead.

How do I add more options to that drop down box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way is to create a module with the following `system.xml` file:

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <google>
            <groups>
                <checkout>
                    <fields>
                        <order_status>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status</source_model>
                        </order_status>
                   <fields>
                <checkout>
            </groups>
        </google>
    </sections>
</config>
```

This will simply make all statuses available.

Comment: That's a great idea clockworkgeek. I'll do it that way! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[New status not appearing on the order list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625413/new-status-not-appearing-on-the-order-list)

Possible module but looks dated:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/eitai2001/extension/1468/order-status

Comment: Thanks for the idea. A little doubtful about the compatibility though.