# New status not appearing on the order list

Tags: php, magento

I created a new status for the orders and it is being set correctly, my problem is that is not appearing on the order list... it is blank where it should be

what should I edit for this to work?

example:

```
 $order->setState('new_status', 'new_status', 'Some comment', false);
 $order->save();
```

thanks,
Joe

Comment: Please provide code samples of the changes you have made. How have you created a new status?

Comment: @clockworkgeek: Edited. I set the order state and saved it as on the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you need to define the status in your module's `config.xml` file.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <sales>
            <order>
                <statuses>
                    <new_status translate="label"><label>Some status</label></new_status>
                </statuses>
            </order>
        </sales>
    </global>
</config>
```

This is how all other status codes are acquired.