# Magento Order Status at Default for Google API

Tags: magento

I have a problem with new orders coming through the Paypal and Google Checkout. Those orders are marked as "Cleared" automatically, while I want them to be "Processing" and process them manually.

in my configuration >> Sales >> Google API

"New Order Status" is set as "Pending" there's only "pending" and "Cancelled" options in drop down there...

As for the Paypal, I have enabled paypal exress checkout, in the "Payment Action" dropdown I have selected "Sale", another option there is "Order"

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks in advance
Regards,
John

Comment: no one ever had this problem? no clues how to solve this issue? : ((

Comment: I am working on this right now, and I am about to extend the Google API, unless you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though the answer to this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629929/870729

Comment: Thanks @cale_b I'll see that : ))